# RSA_Private_Decrypt fails randomly

Tags: c++, openssl, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

I am not a crypto expert, but I wrote encrypt/decrypt methods. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. The **encryptKey** method returns the variable text length every time for the same string, which is may be due to RSA_PKCS1_PADDING which I am using, but for same string of text, the **decryptKey** function fails if the encrypted text length is below some threshold.

```
//----------------------Encryption -----------------------
int Asymmetric::encryptKey(unsigned char *data, int data_len, unsigned char *encrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(1); // Loads the public key
    int result = RSA_public_encrypt(data_len,data,encrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}
//-----------------------Decryption -----------------------
int Asymmetric::decryptKey(unsigned char * enc_data,int data_len, unsigned char *decrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(0); // Loads the private key
    int  result = RSA_private_decrypt(data_len,enc_data,decrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}
```

How i can overcome this situation?

**Edit**: 
This code does not work

```
char *myData = "Sample Text";
unsigned char *encrypt = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_size(rsaPub));
int result = RSA_public_encrypt(RSA_size(rsaPub)-11 ,(unsigned char*)myData,encrypt,rsaPub,padding);
fprintf(stderr, "\nEnc Size: %d \n", strlen((const char*)encrypt));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform padding, cipher text should have fixed size equal to RSA public key modulus. If you get different size every time, then there is something with your program.

When you perform encryption `data` must be less than `RSA_size(rsa) - 11` and `encrypted` must point to `RSA_size(rsa)` bytes of memory.

`strlen(const char * str)` computes length of null-terminated string. `encrypt` is not the string and is not null terminated, so using `strlen` is not valid here. Luckily for you PKCS#1 padding contains zero bytes, so you don't get segmentation fault.

On the other hand `myData` **is** a null terminated string. However, you use `RSA_size(rsaPub) - 11` as its length, which will result in occasional segmentation faults.

Comment: Why RSA_size(rsa) - 11? is 11 a fixed value? I did that, but still the same result.

Comment: Because length of RSA_PKCS1_PADDING is at least 11 bytes. Maybe you should show how you allocate `encrypted` and `decrypted`.

Comment: Please see the edit, i have pasted the code that does not work.

Comment: Yes, it fixed. the problem was with strlen(const char * str). Thank you very much :)